# Pointers and Function Calls

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with this program. Im trying to print out the address of the largest value in an array but i keep getting the address of the first value in the array. I'm pretty sure the problem's in the for loop but i can't figure out where exactly. Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *Largest(int *array, int size);


int main (void)
{
    int* Z;
    int A[10] = {3,53,52,6,2,8,3,6454,232,88};
    Z = Largest(A, 10);


    printf("The address of the largest Value is: %d",  Z);

}

int* Largest(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i++; i<size)
    {
        if (*(array+i) > *array)
        *array = *(array+i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Your function is returning a pointer... why are you not using the `array[i]` subscripting, to make it easier to understand first, and drop the `*` from teh function declaration's return type.

Comment: the problem requires me to use pointer arithmetic and * in the function declaration

Comment: Your type specifier `%d` invokes undefined behaviour. Use the correct one to print a pointer!

Comment: You never change the value of `array` in your function. How do you expect it to change?

Comment: Your code is far from doing what your text describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You are modifying values in the array itself (not keeping track of a pointer) and then just returning the original pointer.
2. Your loop is backwards and never executes (because the termination condition `i++` with initial value of 0 will evaluate to false).

Instead, keep track of a another pointer and do it like this:

```
int i;
int *largest = array;
for( i = 1; i < size; ++i )
{
    if( array[i] > *largest ) largest = &array[i];
}
return largest;
```

If you insist on a purely pointer arithmetic solution, try this:

```
int *end = array + size;
int *largest = array;
for( ; array != end; ++array )
{
    if( *array > *largest ) largest = array;
}
return largest;
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, you also have the wrong `printf` specifier for displaying an address.  Use `%p` instead:

```
printf("The largest Value is: %d",  *Z);
printf("The address of the largest Value is: %p",  Z);
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course, what you are doing in the Largest function is modifying the first element of the array and then returning it. You are modifying `*array`, but not `array` which is what your return.

Answer (score -1):

The first problem is in your **for** loop definition. It should be like that:

> for (i = 0; i < size; i++)

The second problem is that you are modifying your array. Use this code snippet instead:

```
int* Largest(int *array, int size)
{
    int* largest_ptr = array;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i - 1])
        {
            largest_ptr = array + i;
        }
    }
    return largest_ptr;
}
```